# typo3 realurl multiple plugin and controller issue, can't access require parameters

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-7.6.x

I have created a module to show products and its category on front. I have create 3 plugins in this module, one for showing category list (allcategory), one for showing category products list (categoryproduct) and last one is for product's details (productdetail). All plugins were applied on 3 individual pages.

So there URL have their namespace like

1. `/produkte/?tx_wxproducts_allcategory[pcuid]=78&tx_wxproducts_allcategory[controller]=WxCategory`
2. `/produkte/produktdetails/?tx_wxproducts_productdetail[uid]=79&tx_wxproducts_productdetail[controller]=WxProducts`
3. `/produkte/produkte-category/?tx_wxproducts_categoryproduct[cuid]=67&tx_wxproducts_categoryproduct[controller]=WxProducts`

Now, I am writing the rules for realURL configuration to create speaking URLs for these products and category.

Issue is, when go from one plugin to another plugin controller then we do not receive the request variables which are very much required to access the page. I have search on internet and found similar issue reported in 2011: https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/152453/

I didn't have any idea that multi plugin could have given such issue other wise i would have made it with single plugin and services for choosing action but its too late.

I am looking for the solution, i think typo3 mentors can help me out of this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when go from one plugin to another plugin controller"?

Comment: like i said if i am on a page when plugin 1 is applied and it has link to go to plugin 2 then because of namespace change i couldn't get the require parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Build your links like this:

```
<f:link.action pageUid="myTargetPage" action="myAction" controller="WxProducts" pluginName="productdetail" arguments="{uid: '{myVariable}'}"
```

Does this help?

Comment: i have used link.action but didn't used the pluginName, let me try this..

Comment: Yes, i am trying to mark it but i need 15 reputations to do this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Upvoting might not be available but accepting an answer should always work? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: how can i create realURL alias in multilanguage, right now it is creating alias of default language only, i need german text alias for german and english alias is for english language. English is default language in my system.

Comment: This is not really related to the original issue. Please open a new question.